# Memory Consumption Random Forest scikit learn trained in parallel

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining

I'm using Random Forests from scikit-learn in production and I'm trying to minimise and understand their memory footprint. Therefore, I was running a memory profiling for my predicting script. My random forest is loaded from a file which is approximately 40 mb big with 30 subtrees, each about 1mb is size. It was trained parallel on 12 cores. So when executing my profiling script it gave the following output: In the WrapperClass the classifier is loaded in memory.

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
41 579.2 MiB    532.7 MiB       classifier = WrapperClass('test_tree.rf')
```

However, when I'm looking at the same process in htop it shows me that the memory usage is about 4gb? How do this two numbers fit together? Which is the one, I can trust?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: Virtual size 4GB, or resident size?

Comment: 2.5 GB resident and 4 GB virtual